# Run CSS queries against result in controller tests

Tags: ecomdev-phpunit

In `Ecomdev_PHPUnit` is there already the possibility to run CSS queries (assertions) against the output in controller tests or do I have to utilize `Zend_Dom_Query` manually?

Comment: It is currently is not supported, it will be very easy to add such support by creating a test helper for assertion of HTML output. Will give an answer later when implement it, or you are always welcome for PR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this comment](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/654/run-css-queries-against-result-in-controller-tests) from the `Ecomdev_PHPUnit` creator this is not supported.